# Query different tables based upon filter criteria

Tags: sql

I want to create a query that accesses different tables based upon the Where filter applied to it.

For example if the predefined query is queried like this:

```
Select A,B,C,D from the_query
Where A>0 and A<5
[Gets data from source table A0to5_Table)

Select A,B,C,D from the_query
Where A>=5 and A<10
[Gets data from source table A5to10_Table)
```

All the source tables have the same schema. What I would like is a CASE type statement in the query, were the cases are based upon the Where filter.

Is it possible to do this using SQL (PostgreSQL or SQL Server)? Or is the only option to use a stored procedure with parameters?

Comment: Can each column have data coming from a different range of tables i.e. A >= 5 AND < 10 so tables A5 to A9, B > 0 AND B < 5 so tables A0 to A4) or do all columns use the same source tables? You'll be looking to write a [Dynamic SQL statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188001.aspx) most likely.

Comment: How you are passing values to where condition?

Comment: The use case for my example is pre-calculated aggregations where the variable A is a timestamp. For a small range of time (ie 1 day) A>= 1/1/2016 0:00 and A<=2/1/2016 0:00, I would like to query a table with records that contain 1 minute aggregations. But if the time range is large (perhaps a year) A>=1/1/2015 0:00 and A<=1/1/2016 0:00, then I would like to return daily aggregated values. Note I don't want to calculate the aggregations on the fly. The goal is to not return a huge number of records for large time ranges.

Comment: >How you are passing values to where condition?
I'm not passing the values. It is just that the pre-defined query has a where filter applied to it in the (super) query.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in SQL.  One major reason is that storing the same data in different tables is not the SQLish way of storing data.  You should be storing this data in a single table, perhaps with a column to specify additional information.

One thing you can do is `union all` the tables together.  Something like this:

```
select t.*
from ((select t.* from A0to5_Table) union all
      (select t.* from A5to10_Table)
     ) t
where a > 0 and a < 5;
```

You can even use a view for this purpose.

Many databases support the partitioning of tables, using a column as a key.  This gives you the functionality you want, with all the data in a single table.  You would need to consult the documentation for your particular database to see how this applies in your case.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Did you see I clarified above that column A is a timestamp. Okay, lets say I put all the data in the same table and use an additional column to encode the time resolution of A (for example, minute, hourly, daily), is there a way that I can get the query to automatically determine the resolution column filter, based upon the range of A values queried? (Hope that makes sense).

Comment: @SteveS. . . . It is best to ask questions as *questions* and not in comments.  Please ask another question with sample data and desired results.